# Character limitation of MFMessageComposeViewController in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

How many characters can be send in text sms through MFMessageComposeViewController in iphone and ipad.

Answer (score 2):

There is not real maximum, since SMS 160 characters it will send more then one SMS when you have more then 160 characters.

If you read the [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation there is no mentions about maximum body length.